# php,unix command ,imagick help me

Tags: php, unix, command, imagemagick

This command add the text "flower" to the image:

```
convert flower.jpg -font courier -fill white -pointsize 20 -annotate +50+50 'Flower' flower_annotate1.jpg
```

I'm using ImageMagick 2.2.0. I'm running it from PHP using:

```
system('convert flower.jpg -font courier -fill white -pointsize 20 -annotate +50+50 'Flower' flower_annotate1.jpg');
```

but I'm not getting the result

Comment: I am wondering why you are not getting a `PARSE ERROR`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872833/php-unix-command-imagick-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single-quotes in the parameters:

```
system('convert flower.jpg -font courier -fill white -pointsize 20 -annotate +50+50 \'Flower\' flower_annotate1.jpg');
```

Or just wrap the thing in double-quotes so you don't have to escape them.