# php,unix command ,imagick ,overflow

Tags: php, unix, command, imagick

This is Add text to image

```
echo system('convert mug.jpg -font courier -fill green -pointsize 30 -annotate +100+230 \'hi Wlecome yy\'   mug123.jpg');
```

unix command run in php it is working fine when we change the point size  hi welcome is over flow the image

how can we over come?

Answer (score 1):

You want a large line of text on top of a small image? I'd expect it to overflow. You could put two lines of text one below the other.

However, since you're doing this in PHP, I'd recommend you use an image library like [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) rather than shell out for imagemagick.